# Is 모자라다 a verb or an adjective

Tags: grammar, orthography

I learned that 모자라다 is an adjective, which means that it should be conjugated as such, e.g.,

> 시간이 모자라서 빨리 빨리 해야돼.
>
> 전 모자란 것들이 많은데 열심히 하겠습니다.

But on the internet I sometimes find it written with a verb conjugation:

> *일은 많은데 손이 모자란다.* instead of *일은 많은데 손이 모자라다.*
>
> *돈이 아직 모자라는 것 같은데.* instead of *돈이 아직 모자란 것 같은데.*

Does this mean that it's okay to use both adjective and verb conjugation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

모자라다 is a verb in Korean, so you need to conjugate the word according to the verb rule, despite having an adjective meaning. However it is an intransitive verb, which means you cannot have object attached to it.

Example: 힘이 모자라서... Without enough power...

아/어 conjugation is the same for verbs and adjectives, so I don't see any example showing 모자라다 as an adjective.

Comment: Then sentences like *전 모자란 것들이 많으데 열심히 하겠습니다*  is the past tense of 모자라다  and not ㄴ/은 for adjectives

Comment: Correct, and it makes sense to be past tense